# PHP MySQL connection without socket file

Tags: php, mysql, sockets

If the socket file reporting in phpinfo() does not exist, does it create a TCP connection to the MySQL server?

I am asking because A is a web server and B is a MySQL server.  A does not have the /var/lib/mysql directory as defined in phpinfo() but it is still able to connect to server B.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If they're distinct servers, then it'd be a TCP connection. file sockets do not function over the network - they're local usage only.

Answer (score 0):

The socket is the default for connecting to a local MySQL server. Otherwise, a TCP connection is used.

If you want to use a TCP connection for a local server, use the following:

`mysql -h 127.0.0.1 -P 3306`